# ElasticSearch - Multi-match Query returning no hits for data even though its there - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, booleanquery

I'm trying to fetch a list of items that have the field: `resellable: true`.

Here is my data set I can see by visiting: `my-domain.com/_all/listings/_search`

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "collectibles",
        "_type" : "listing",
        "_id" : "SseZfNbpdpBxc3O",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "data" : {
            "resellable" : true,
            "active" : true,
            "description" : "<p>1234 123 123 123</p>",
            "title" : "2134",
            "has_store" : true,
            "createdAt" : "Wed May 27 2020 04:23:18 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
            "apiURL" : "kJ9zsIsdQG8TZrRfPco4",
            "id" : "SseZfNbpdpBxc3O",
            "state" : "PENDING",
            "amount" : "21",
          }
        }
      }
}
```

My query is using `*NodeJS and ElasticSearch.js*`

```
let results = await client.search({
    index: params.category,
    type: "listing",
    body: {
        query: {
            multi_match: {
                query: true,
                fields: ['resellable', 'active'],
                type: 'best_fields',
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The response is always *`no hits`*. I've tried a `match`, I've tried no `best_fields` and it doesn't seem to match the value.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something else you need to do to query the `_source.data` level items?

`ElasticSearch version: 7.4`

Comment: 'resellable', 'active' should be 'data.resellable', data.'active'. If you will look at your output resellable and active and part of data field "_source" : {
          "data" : {
            "resellable" : true   or you need to correct your document structure while indexing (remove data)

Comment: @jaspreetchahal yes that did it. Thank you. Why is it only "data.active" instead of "_source.data.active"?

Comment: _source is an internal field in elastisearch which contains all the field, it is not added explicitly by us so no need to specify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `"true"` in string format when using multi_match, while you indexed data in boolean format `true` and thats the reason you are not getting any hits.

I just noticed both of your `multi_match` fields(`resellable` and `active`) are boolean then why you are using the multi_match query, you should instead use the [boolean filter query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) which is cached as well and gives better performance.

From the doc

**Filter clauses are executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for caching.**

**Sample index Mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "active": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "resellable" :{
                "type" : "boolean"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index various example  documents**

```
{
   "active" : true,
   "resellable" : true
}

{
   "active" : true,
   "resellable" : false
}

{
   "active" : false,
   "resellable" : false
}

{
   "active" : false,
   "resellable" : true
}
```

**Search query to get the doc where both values are true**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "active": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "resellable": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
 "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "filterbool",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.0,
            "_source": {
               "active": true,
               "resellable": true
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: I just tested without a string value and a boolean instead and it still returns zero hits. I've updated my post to reflect this. 

For the filter query - how do I set multiple fields for resellable and active?

Comment: @Zach thanks I am working on to provide a working sample.

Comment: @Zach, you want both `resellable`  and `active` to be true correct as mentioned in your sample doc.

Comment: My query is dynamic, a user might have resellable, and no active, or active and no resellable. So I have an array with the filter options I pass into the "fields". But since I was returning 0 hits I hard coded the values to see if it was a problem with formatting or I was getting nothing regardless of formating. Filter query via terms seems like I might not be able to do dynamic terms?

Comment: @Zach, got it shouldn't be issue, I just got the solution and updating the answer(hint, you need to use the filter in your search query and refer the boolean filter query link in my answer)

Comment: @Zach did you solve it, I saw in question comments and overlooked the `data` field in your case but ideally you should use the filter clause to construct these queries as mentioned in the link and updated my answer with same `Filter clauses are executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for caching.`

Comment: @Zach could you please check my last comments and reply :) Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the replies. You helped a bunch and the issue is solved. it was an issue with data.resellable and not resellable, also with "true" and true typings

Comment: @Zach wow thanks a lot for following up and accepting the answer, it would help other readers and it would be great if you can upvote the answer if not done already, I just did on your question :)